# What am I? Where do I live?

Tags: riddle

My head: A d20.

My legs: A spider.

I love to walk *all* over you.

---

**Have fun.**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE; this is an interesting first puzzle! Go ahead and [take the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and fill out your [profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50271/theunknown) for a couple of quick [badges](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges). Good Luck

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you ...

> a virus ?

My head:

> There is the "Adenovirus" who has a icosahedral capsid which translates to a capsule with 20 faces. Also, a D20 is a kind of dice with 20 faces (commonly used on D&D games).

My legs:

> A Bacteriophage is a virus that infects bacteria and its body structure looks just like a spider.

Where do i live:

> Viruses infect life forms (like us... HUMANS!) And they love to walk all over us because that's the only way they can multiply. So, basically, they are "dead" while not inside a life form. In that case, they "live" inside any life form.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  We usually put answers in spoiler blocks to preserve the mystery for future would-be solvers. I've added them for you.

Comment: I was looking for the way to hide my answers but i could not find them. I so so so so sorry, thanks for that link !